# SharePoint 2013 - Workflows: Why am I getting a (no title) link in my email messages?

Tags: workflow, error

**Note: Not using SharePoint Designer 2013 since it has been discontinued!**

---

**EDIT: Problem solved!** - The default "Title" field was hidden and was void of data. Once I un-hid, modified, and populated with data, the emails appeared with the data I entered."

---

Does anyone have a workaround for the (no title) issue with workflow generated emails in SharePoint 2013 List workflows?

I have an approval workflow set up on a list form that emails the "Approver" when a form requires approval (associated with "This List" in the workflows dropdown).

The emails I am receiving look like:

[image: Email Message]

I have a Title column set in the list that has a default value assigned to it (just a name of the form). However, the email/workflow isn't recognizing the item title.

If I switch tracks and create a different workflow based on an Item, upon submission of the form, I receive an error stating the following:

[image: Warning Message]

I am not quite sure how to bind the Title column/field to the workflow since there is no default option to set it when initially generating the workflow (by list or by item). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!